# homotopy groups of Wu manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

I'm interested in the homotopy groups of the Wu manifold $ W=SU_3/SO_3 $. From LES homotopy we have
$$
\pi_1(W)=\pi_0(SO_3)=0
$$
since $ SU_3 $ simply connected
$$
\pi_2(W)=\pi_1(SO_3)=C_2
$$
since $ \pi_2(SU_3) $ vanishes, as it does for every lie group. Finally we have
$$
\pi_3(SU_3)=\mathbb{Z} \to \pi_3(W) \to 0=\pi_2(SO_3)
$$
so $ \pi_3(W) $ must be cyclic. Hopefully this question isn't to broad. I'm interested in all homotopy groups but I would especially like to know which cyclic group $ \pi_3(W) $ is. Mostly I'm just in it to learn new tricks for calculating homotopy groups of $ SU_3 $ and $ SO_3 \cong \mathbb{R}P^3 $ and seeing how these can be used to calculate homotopy groups of $ G/H $.

Comment: What is the third homology of $W$? Hurewicz says that $\pi_3(W)$ also surjects on to that.